# Contadores separados SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi pregunta es la siguiente tengo una columna calculada que concatena un valor con el numero de columna para generar el campo:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo (
    ID INT IDENTITY, 
    NumeroRadicado AS ('AG' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 15) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID),15)) PERSISTED NOT NULL, 
    Dato VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Ejemplo (Dato) VALUES ('Dato1') , ('Dato2')

SELECT  *
FROM #Ejemplo
```

Resultado:

```
╔══════╦═══════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID   ║ NumeroRadicado    ║ Dato  ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1,00 ║ AG000000000000001 ║ Dato1 ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2,00 ║ AG000000000000002 ║ Dato2 ║
╚══════╩═══════════════════╩═══════╝
```

La duda que tengo es, si es posible generar una tabla donde tenga la columna del contador separada y al generar el insert este revise en esa otra tabla para tomar el dato del contador

Muchas gracias por sus aportes

Comment: ¿qué es lo que persigues con esto?

Comment: @jachguate No tener la columna calculada si no ir sumando en otra tabla el contador

Comment: Sigo sin comprender cuál es la idea detrás.

Comment: @jachguate La idea es tener en tbl1 un campo llamado consecutivo, pero este campo llenarlo con el autoincremental de otra tabla osea tbl2 en tbl2 tener los campos de los  consecutivos ejemplo AG | AB | y cuando en tbl1 haga un insert este le sume 1 al campo AG para que quede AG1 y asi sucesivamente

Comment: De verdad sigo sin entenderlo, eso que dices se puede hacer, pero ¿cuál es la dificultad que tienes al hacerlo?